# How to get user input/arguments after the command was called in discord.js v13.0 (so not the args method)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I've been working on this discord bot that takes '/' commands in order to display details about the user's (for the game osu!) most recent play, their top play, etc. However, I've been struggling with trying to take in arguments using the '/' commands to try and add their username onto the bot's database. I understand how to approach adding their username onto a database but I don't understand how to get an argument they send in addition to the /set command. For example, I want to retrive the String 'David' if they give the command '/set David'

Here's my index.js which is from the discord.js v13.0 documentation:

```
    const fs = require('node:fs');
    const { Client, Collection, Intents, User } = require('discord.js');
    const { token } = require('./config.json');
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');

    const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
    
    client.commands = new Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    }

    client.once('ready', () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });
    client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

And here's the skeleton code for the command file where I want to have the discord user give their osu! username as an argument:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { v1, auth } = require('osu-api-extended');
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('set')
        .setDescription('Allows the user to add their osu! username onto the bot\'s system'),
    async execute(interaction) {

    },
};
```

Comment: Is there a specific error message that you are getting or what exactly is it that you can't get to work with the '/' commands?

Comment: It's not really an error message rather than me wanting to figure out how to work with getting an argument to pass from a command. I've tried what Cannicide suggessted by adding a constant and delcaring it to be interaction.options.getString('username'), however I've been getting null as the result.

Comment: Well, you need to setup the argument in your command file before trying to access its value, otherwise the argument does not actually exist. It doesn't appear to be setup in the code you've shown. Underneath `.setDescription()`, you need to use [`.addStringOption()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/stable/class/SlashCommandBuilder?scrollTo=addStringOption) and setup the `username` argument. Once you've done that, then my answer will work for you in getting the argument value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Take a look at the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=options).

```js
const arg = interaction.options.getString("insert argument name here");
```

That is the basic format for getting the value of a `String` argument. If you have a different type of argument such as integer or boolean, you would use `getInteger()` or `getBoolean()` respectively instead of `getString()`. The methods for each different type of argument are fully documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver).

As a more specific example, let's say you have a command like this: `/set <username>`, where the command is named "set" and the argument is named "username." This is how you would get the username value in that instance:

```js
const username = interaction.options.getString("username");
```

For questions regarding how to do basic discord.js actions like this one, I would recommend taking a look at the official djs documentation before asking a question here. The docs will always have the answer to such questions, and usually those answers aren't too difficult to find.